# disabling ethernet loopback packets

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, python, pcap

I have a linux machine with a few network interfaces which I use to run communication tests. In some of the tests I get a lot of packets with ether type 0x9000 (ethernet configuration testing protocol). This makes my packet analysis test run slower and it sometimes fails. Is there any way to disable these packets?

I also tried using a "not ether proto 0x9000" when I capture the packets in pcapy but that didn't work for me (I saw the packets after applying the filter).

Edit - I looked at a capture of these loopback packets and they seem to arrive from another interface on the same machine, it is an interface created by kvm with an e1000 driver.